# How to set view to a specific fragment when clicked recognized in navigation drawer in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have used a sectionsPageAdapter class in Java which is given below.
This is a tabbed activity and I later added a navigation drawer to it.
Now I wish to let user navigate through tabs from the main activity by swiping (which works successfully) and also through nav drawer as I have included the same fragments names there also.
what code should i write in the switch case to direct user to the clicked fragment activity?

Main Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG,"onCreate: Starting");

        mSectionsPageAdapter =new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager =(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.container);
        setupViewPager(mViewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        mDrawerLayout =(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);
        addDrawerItems();
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position)
                {
                    case 0:
                          // what Code??
                        break;
                    case 1:

                        break;
                }
            }
        });

    }


    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
        SectionsPageAdapter adapter=new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment(),"Our Picks");
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab2Fragment(),"Technology");
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab3Fragment(),"Fashion");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void addDrawerItems() {
        String[] osArray = { "Our Picks", "Technology","Fashion" };
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.drawerpart1, osArray);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
```

SectionsPageAdapter.java

```
public class SectionsPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList=new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList=new ArrayList<>();

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment,String title){
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);

    }


    public SectionsPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.aa.news.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/navList"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:background="#ffeeeeee"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

drawerpart1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

Tab1Fragment

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "Tab1Fragment";
    private Button btn1;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@Nullable LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_fragment,container,false);
        btn1=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Button 1 Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        return view;


    }





}
```

tab1_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:text="Fragment 1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The other fragments tab2 and 3 are same as tab 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setCurrentItem() on viewpager

```
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick (AdapterView < ? > parent, View view,int position, long id){
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks!
Can you also tell me where should I add an Image View to navigation drawer if I wanted it to display above the current elements in nav drawer?

Comment: if you want to display images in each of list item ,you have to create a custom adapter

Comment: No not in each of the items , just one ImageView above all items 
(Like user icon in gmail)

Comment: use NavigationView inside your DrawerLayout and add         app:headerLayout="@layout/some_layout_with_image" inside NavigationView.